# Como eu faço essa query com subselect no laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, query

Tentei de todo jeito, mas ele não monta pra mim o `SubSelect`. Usei o método  `toSql()` pra confirmar e realmente ele não monta.

***SQL***

```
SELECT p.descr,p.dt_hr, (SELECT u1.name FROM users u1 WHERE u1.id = f.id_friend) AS name
FROM friends f JOIN users u ON u.id = f.id_user
               JOIN posts p ON p.id_user = f.id_friend
WHERE u.id = 1
ORDER BY p.dt_hr DESC
```

Comment: tentei essa query aqui, mas sem resultado.

$posts = DB::table('friends')
            ->select('friends.*')
            ->addSelect(DB::raw("(SELECT u1.name FROM users u1 WHERE u1.id = friends.id_friend) AS name"))
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends.id_user')
            ->join('posts', 'posts.id_user', '=', 'friends.id_friend')
            ->select('posts.dt_hr', 'posts.descr', 'name')
            ->where('users.id', $id_user)
            ->orderBy('posts.dt_hr', 'desc')
            ->get();

Comment: RESOLVI JÁ:

$posts = DB::table('friends')
->select('posts.dt_hr', 'posts.descr', 'name', (DB::raw("(SELECT u1.name FROM users u1 WHERE u1.id = friends.id_friend) AS name")))
->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends.id_user')
->join('posts', 'posts.id_user', '=', 'friends.id_friend')
->where('users.id', $id_user)
->orderBy('posts.dt_hr', 'desc')
->get();

Comment: Coloque como resposta @Leonardo ... então ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvido!

```
$posts = DB::table('friends') 
        ->select('posts.dt_hr', 'posts.descr', 'name',
        (DB::raw("(SELECT u1.name FROM users u1 WHERE u1.id = friends.id_friend) AS name")))
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'friends.id_user')
        ->join('posts', 'posts.id_user', '=', 'friends.id_friend')
        ->where('users.id', $id_user)
        ->orderBy('posts.dt_hr', 'desc')
        ->get();
```